# Modify Table-Valued Parameters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I have created a `Table-Valued Parameters` on my `SQL Server 2008 R2` install.  I created a field as a `varchar(25)` and now I need to modify it to a `DateTime`

What would be the process for doing such?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - what is syntax to drop?  If I created with CREATE TYPE dbo.TableValue_Test AS TABLE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to drop the type and then re-create it. You will have to modify all the modules that use it first, so a better and less disruptive option might be to create a *new* table type with the right data type, modify each of the modules to point at the new type, then drop the old one.

The syntax is simply:

```
DROP TYPE dbo.TableValue_Test;
```

However this will fail while modules still reference the type. If the TVP is only referenced in client code, you might have less to worry about, but you should still update the app code to use the right data type from end to end.